# Duplicate an element independently of the original

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to duplicate a class and to make it not change when the original is changed. currently I tried

```
$(".newclass").addClass("oldclass");
```

which  does  not copy the content

```
var _elementClone = $(".oldclass").html();
$(".newclass").html(_elementClone);

this one is good and transfers all the contents of the  div
```

PROBLEM: in all cases when I change the oldclass parent.  like

```
$('.oldclass').hide();

<style> 
.oldclass{visibility:collapse}
</style>
```

the new one also changes.
How can I create  new class which does not change when the parent is changed?

Comment: Just so you know, `.newclass.oldclass` isn't the same as `.newclass .oldclass` or `.oldclass .newclass` but it's the same as `.oldclass.newclass`

Comment: In other words, what you're actually doing is to add a new `class` to elements that already contain certain `class`. You're not creating any `parent - child` relationship.

Comment: thanks unfortunately these are just names i came up with for the question

Comment: The names you're giving don't really matter. You're just seeing things in the wrong way.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: just so you know, visibility:collapse is only meant for table elements. so you're adding the oldclass to the elem with newclass and don't expect the behaviour you're expecting from the oldclass on the newclass ? why you adding .oldclass to it then.

Comment: The element with class `newclass` will now have both `newclass` and `oldclass`. That's what your first piece code is doing. The second bit is just replacing the element's content with its own content (nothing changes). The last one is hiding the element. So... You always had just one element.

Comment: and whats the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can duplicate the element by getting it's outer HTML, use jQuery to change it's id, class or whatever, and then insert it into the DOM to have independent elements.

EXAMPLE

HTML:

```
<div id="first" class="top">First Div</div>
<div id="second" class="middle">Second Div</div>
<div id="third" class="middle">Third Div</div>
<div id="last" class="bottom">Last Div</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var divs=$(".middle");

$.each(divs,function(i,el) {
    var newdiv = $(el.outerHTML);
    newdiv.attr("id",newdiv.attr("id")+"-copy");
    newdiv.removeClass("middle").addClass("middle-copy");
    divs.eq(i).after(newdiv); 
});
$("#second-copy").html("copy of second div");
$("#third").html("original third div");
setInterval('$(".middle-copy").toggle()',1000);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0cy0gvj9/2/

Comment: This is great. unfortunately it adds the new clas/Id just after the parent. How can I have the freedom to choose where the   newclass is  placed? Thanks

Comment: [`.after(newdiv)`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) is what adds the new element to the page.  Just use the selector for the object you want it to follow instead of `divs.eq(i)`, or use [`.before`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) or [`.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: I'm new to javascript/jquery, I can't understand what you mean

Comment: Decide where you want to put the new element in your page, then use the jQuery [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to get the adjacent/parent element, so `$("#elid").after(newdiv)` to put the new element after the element with id 'elid', `$(".classname").before(newdiv)` to put it before the first element with the class 'classname', or `$("div.dynamic").append(newdiv)` to put it after the last child in the first div with the class 'dynamic'.  I linked to the jQuery docs in my previous comment, each page there has more in-depth examples.

Answer (score 0):

In the first line you're assigning `.newclass` to `.oldclass`. So, when later you hide `.oldclass`, this selector will include the previous assignment. That is, since all `.newclass` items are also `.oldclass` ones, they get hidden as well.

The function you're looking for is `.append()`, which will append a child to a given element (thus making it a parent).